# Source of truth for port registration internally in multiple microservice ecosystem

Tags: microservices, scaling

It is a general question on managing ports assignment and having a single source of truth for ports. When we have multiple micro-services and configured behind TCP/HTTP/gRPC high-availability services (haproxy / envoy).

How do other organisation manage port assignment in 100-1000s of micro-services.

Comment: could you say if you are on cloud or premises and more about your architecture configuration?

Comment: c4f4t0r: will approach differ for cloud or premises or hybrid environment?

Comment: an example, if you are on cloud and you want to expose a service to the external cluster network you need to set in your service type: loadbalancer and the network port mapping is handler automacaly by kubernetes

Comment: Actually, it is not about exposing ports. It is more of having a solution around port registry that is used as a source of truth while assigning ports to any tier whether it is datastore, k8s nodeport or abc service in loadbalancer.

Comment: I think that your question is so generic, if we are talking about ports, we need to specify the service type that we are talking about.